# How to make my sidebar fit only inside the outer div

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

This is my `Vue` code and I am using `bootstrap-vue`, I am using the sidebar inside the card body Ideally it should only appear inside the card-body but it's not working. How can I make it fit either inside the outer div or b-card body?

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <div>
      <b-card title="Card Title" body-class="text-center" header-tag="nav">
        <template v-slot:header>
          <b-nav card-header tabs>
            <b-nav-item active>Active</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item>Inactive</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
          </b-nav>
        </template>

        <b-card-text>
          With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
        </b-card-text>
        <b-card-body>
          <b-sidebar visible="true" title="Sidebar" shadow>
            <div class="px-3 py-2">
              <p>
                Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo
                odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo
                risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
              </p>
              <b-img
                src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=54"
                fluid
                thumbnail
              ></b-img>
            </div>
          </b-sidebar>
        </b-card-body>

        <b-button variant="primary">Go somewhere</b-button>
      </b-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sidebar wasn't really designed to be inside a container. but instead be used as an off-canvas menu for the entire page.

However, you can hack it a bit to fit your needs with a little CSS.
The sidebar is `position: fixed` by default, so that it is fixed to the viewport.

You need to change this to `position: absolute`, so that it will be positioned based on the closest parent that is `position: relative`. In this case that's the card.

In the snippet the sidebar goes over the title. If you want it only inside the body, all you need to be is wrap it in another element with `position: relative`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.my-sidebar.b-sidebar-outer {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.my-sidebar .b-sidebar {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-1>Toggle Sidebar</b-button>
  <!-- The height is only here for the example -->
  <b-card style="min-height: 300px;" class="overflow-hidden" no-body>
    <b-card-header>
      <b-card-title>Title</b-card-title>
    </b-card-header>
    <b-sidebar id="sidebar-1" title="Sidebar" shadow class="my-sidebar">
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
       <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
        </p>
        <b-img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=54" fluid thumbnail></b-img>
        <p>
          Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
        </p>
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I've been facing some problems opening the sidebar with a button inside the card, after I clicked the first time the button was not clickable anymore, so to solve that I had to control the state of the sidebar by myself. Something like this:

`<b-sidebar v-if="opened" title="Sidebar"  id="fake-app-menu" class="fake-app-menu" v-model="opened"></b-sidebar>

 <b-button @click="opened = true">Open</b-button>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved by modifying the style of the element by using JQuery where `top': '60px'` is going to be the hight of the navbar.

```
mounted() {
   $('#sidebar-1').css(
     {'top': '60px',
       'opacity': '80%'       
     }
    );
},
```